# Drupal .htaccess rewrite/substitution without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting

I have a URL as follows: `www.site.com/catalog/?type=6`  which I need to rewrite to `www.site.com/white-wines/white-cases`.

What is important is that it is not a redirect, for example the URL should remain as `www.site.com/white-wines/white-cases` when visited, but show content from `www.site.com/catalog/?type=6`.

The current solution that I have performs a redirect and I'm struggling to work this out.

```
RewriteRule ^white-wines/white-cases$ http://www.site.co.uk/catalog/?type=6 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting full address in the target implies a redirect if the target is different then the current hostname, not rewrite. Try root-relative path.

```
RewriteRule ^white-wines/white-cases$ /catalog/?type=6 [L]
```

You can't do a re-write to a different hostname.

> Absolute URL
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to
> see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the
> scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated
> as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the
> given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see
> the [R] flag below.
>
> Source: [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Thanks Nir, I have tried that also but it seems it is being handled somewhere else in the .htaccess since I'm getting a page not found error from Drupal. Here is my full .htaccess http://pastie.org/5028660 . Thanks

Comment: Try removing the [L] from this rule. What happens now is that this is the last rule processes so the default drupal rules do not get used.

Comment: No luck, Drupal is still giving page not found

Comment: I've got the same problem - something about drupal doesn't like the rewrite rule unless it actually redirects the user - did you ever find a solution to this?